# pypy3, установка модулей

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypy

Не удается установить модули в **pypy3**. Пример:

```
$ pypy3 -V
Python 3.6.9 (7.3.0+dfsg-1~ppa1~ubuntu18.04, Dec 24 2019, 08:12:19)
[PyPy 7.3.0 with GCC 7.4.0]

$pypy3 -m pip install Flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pypy3/lib-python/3/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/pypy3/lib-python/3/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/pypy3/lib-python/3/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.retrying import retry
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.retrying'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам же и отвечу.

Качаем pip отсюда: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py  
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1764k  100 1764k    0     0  1578k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 1580k
```

Устанавливаем:

```
$ pypy3 get-pip.py
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-45.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (584 kB)
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel
Successfully installed pip-20.0.2 setuptools-45.2.0 wheel-0.34.2
```

Проверяем:

```
$ pypy3 -m pip install flask
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting flask
  Using cached Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting Werkzeug>=0.15
  Downloading Werkzeug-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 298 kB 927 kB/s 
Collecting Jinja2>=2.10.1
  Downloading Jinja2-2.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 126 kB 1.6 MB/s 
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.24
  Using cached itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting click>=5.1
  Using cached Click-7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (81 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->flask) (1.0)
Installing collected packages: Werkzeug, Jinja2, itsdangerous, click, flask
Successfully installed Jinja2-2.11.1 Werkzeug-1.0.0 click-7.0 flask-1.1.1 itsdangerous-1.1.0
```

Как видим, всё установилось.